# how do you reduce the space between cuts when you use 'loop cut and slide'?

Tags: modeling, mesh

how do you reduce the space between cuts when you use 'loop cut and slide'?

Comment: if I got what you mean, you first apply the cuts then you can "scale" or "slide" them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hover over the mesh, wait for the loop cut appear on the mesh, click once and now you may move the mouse to move the loop cut to left, right, up or down as you like.

[image]

If you want to looking for multiple loop cuts at once, you may scroll the mouse wheel to have mulitple loops like this

[image]

Comment: I'd add that you can also select those same cuts and scale them on an axis, freehand or proportionally if you want a certain number but not the autospaced width.